# Loading activity in Fragment Code

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Can we load an activity (specifically in onCreateView) in fragment ?  Instead of creating view by inflater, can we launch activity so it's events gets called ?

For e.g.

Instead of using "inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabactivity, null)", can we launch activity which uses "tabactivity" as layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. You must create a Fragment Activity that will be used to refer to any fragment you create.

This is a good place to start:

[Fragments Examples](https://github.com/bmeike/Fragments)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible you cannot add `Activity` inside a `fragment`.
`Fragment` is part of UI component of `Activity`.

Refer below link

[Docs for fragment in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)